# how to fix error when debugging a OpenSceneGraph sample project

Tags: openscenegraph

```
`#include <osgDB/ReadFile>
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
    viewer.setSceneData(osgDB::readNodeFile("cessna.osg"));
    return viewer.run();
}

`
```

Exception thrown at 0x7618A832 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x004FF994.

Exception thrown at 0x7618A832 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x004FF0B8.

Exception thrown at 0x7618A832 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

Unhandled exception at 0x7618A832 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x004FF0B8.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough information to help you in this case. Where is the Exception thrown (i.e. which line)?

> Exception thrown at 0x7618A832 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

I assume because of this Exception that your `readNodeFile` doesn't find (and thus doesn't return) the cessna file. Try an absolute path here to make sure the cessna file is found.